# Help setting up my development environment for building a custom community for existing org

Tags: salesforcedx, lightning-community, community-builder, npsp

I'm a volunteer developer working with a non-profit to help them implement a "donor account" functionality to let their donors view their past contributions and projects they've contributed to. The non profit uses Salesforce NPSP. I'm new to the Salesforce platform and trying to wrap my head around what I need to do to get started. From the training I've done, it looks like I should be using source driven development with SFDX. The issue is that the production org doesn't have an existing code repository. My understanding is that I should:

1. Create a new SFDX project folder.
2. Create GitHub repository and sync it with project folder.
3. Import meta-data from the production org which will contain various NPSP specific objects and customizations I will need to interact with as part of the community.
4. Convert meta-data to source format.
5. Import sample data from prod org to project.
6. Create scratch org.
7. Configure community in scratch org.
8. Build custom LWC and add them to the community via the community builder in scratch org
9. Pull remote changes from scratch org to project.
10. Commit changes to git.
11. Create unlocked package and release it.
12. Install it to prod org.

Does the above sound correct?
The part where I'm struggling a bit is how to pull the correct sources from the prod org. One video tutorial I saw suggests creating an unmanaged package from the prod org and downloading its sources via the metadata API. I've tried to do that, but I'm a bit unsure as to what dependencies to include (e.g. Non Profit CRM? Custom Objects? other stuff... ?).

If there's a simpler or better approach, I'd be glad to hear about it. Again, I'm totally new to Salesforce and I'm still struggling to make sense of all the documentation and codelabs I've been looking at. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 6):

*Disclosure: I am on the CumulusCI team at Salesforce.org and am one of the release engineers for the Nonprofit Success Pack*.

### General NPSP Guidance

Because the Nonprofit Success Pack is a complex suite of six managed packages and additional unpackaged metadata, we strongly recommend using CumulusCI, our free and open source build orchestration tool that works with Salesforce DX, to build scratch orgs with NPSP.

We recently released a six-module Trailhead trail, [Build Applications with CumulusCI](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/build-applications-with-cumulusci), that teaches how to use CumulusCI to build applications with this tool. The final module, [CumulusCI for Post-Install Customizations](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/cumulusci-for-postinstall-customizations?trail_id=build-applications-with-cumulusci), walks through the process of creating a project using CumulusCI and Salesforce DX that extends the Nonprofit Success Pack.

### Your Specific Situation

The pathway you laid out looks pretty solid - it sounds like you've digested the thesis of source-driven development thoroughly. I'll sketch out a little more detail around how you'd achieve this with CumulusCI.

The first step, as you already know, is to locate the metadata you want from your production org (*other* than NPSP itself - your dependencies will handle installing that for you with CumulusCI), and get this metadata into a source repository. One route to do that is to create an unmanaged package in your production org and add the metadata making up your application to that package. Salesforce will try to help you out by spidering dependencies and including them too, but this is nonetheless often an iterative and error-prone process. You'll want to include, for example, custom fields you've created on NPSP objects, as well as your own custom objects and Apex code and other work, but not the NPSP's own components (you can generally identify them by having a namespace prefix, such as `npsp__` or `npe04__`).

Once you identify your metadata fully, you can extract the content of that unmanaged package with CumulusCI via

```
cci org connect production
cci task run retrieve_packaged --org production -o package <name of unmanaged package>
```

You'll then get down a package of metadata, by default in the folder `packaged`, that you can convert into Salesforce DX format if desired with `sfdx force:mdapi:convert`, and that metadata can form the basis of your project.

You can capture a sample data set using CumulusCI's [bulk data tooling](https://cumulusci.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bulk_data.html) and make it part of your repository to add into each scratch org. We walk through that process in [Data Management with CumulusCI](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/data-management-with-cumulusci?trail_id=build-applications-with-cumulusci) on Trailhead.

Once you've got your metadata and data squared away, you'd build a scratch org using

```
cci flow run dev_org --org dev
```

which would automatically contain NPSP, your custom metadata, and your sample data set.

In the scratch org, you'd build out your work, and capture it locally with a task like

```
cci task run retrieve_changes --org dev
```

Committing that code to a feature branch ([CumulusCI Flow](https://cumulusci.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cumulusci_flow.html)) helps you manage review and ensure you're merging the changes you want to merge into your mainline.

As a note, Communities are one of the more challenging features of Salesforce to work with in source control. Consider exploring the new `ExperienceBundle` feature, which was GA in Spring '20 and needs to be explicitly turned on in your org settings (part of the [SFDX scratch org definition file](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm), or in Salesforce Setup). That feature promises to make retrieval, source management, and redeployment of Community metadata somewhat easier, and gives you nicer, textual-format metadata to work with.

When you're ready to install into production, you can either deploy directly from your source tree, or build an unlocked package as you describe. I'll stop there as I've never actually build at NPSP-dependent unlocked package - hopefully other contributors can talk more about that end stage of the process.

### Resources

- [Build Applications with CumulusCI](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/build-applications-with-cumulusci)
- [NPSP Open Source Project](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/NPSP)
- [CumulusCI Trailblazer Community Group](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000009M9ZCAU)
- Make sure to join the Power of Us Hub (available only to nonprofit/education community members) and join the CumulusCI group, Nonprofit Developer group, and others that'll be very relevant to this project. The Hub has a large and helpful community that can guide you along.

Comment: Thank you David for your thorough response. I'll look into CumulusCI and ExperienceBundle. I appreciate the prompt and detailed reply.